# jQuery Sortable on column layout with 0 margin

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I think I'm almost there with my sortable implementation but am still getting some small issues that perhaps someone here can help with.

To give you a brief idea I have a group of divs in a container div as follows:

```
<div id="sample-list">
    <div class="sample">one</div>
    <div class="sample">two</div>
    <div class="sample">three</div>
    <div class="sample">four</div>
    <div class="sample">five</div>
    <div class="sample">six</div>
</div>
```

With the following css (more or less):

```
#sample-list {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-content: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    width: 320px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 30px;
}

.sample {
    width: 80px;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    background: #fff;
    text-align:center;

    &:nth-child(3n + 3) {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

The issue came in with the 0 margin on every 3rd element so I had to reset the css on the sort, change and stop events of sortable. I'll add my solution as an answer...

My questions are as follows:

1. What is the best way to reset the margins in sortable, especially on a grid with a 0 margin in the right (or left) column?
2. What is a reliable way to avoid the element jumping when first starting to sort?

Very interested to hear your thoughts. If nothing else, I hope I make it a bit easier for you to get sortable working reliably.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this isn't very elegant but it was the only way I could get around it.

Question 1:
I noticed that the placeholder is added as an element to the list when you click and hold the element and the element itself is set to `position: absolute`, breaking it out of the DOM. This resets the 3n + 3 count to be off by one so the rest of the elements jump to adjust.

My solution was to reset the margins on all the contained elements using this:

```
$("#sample-list").sortable({
    // Stop the page from scrolling:
    scroll: false,

    'start': function(event, ui) {
        var resetGroup = (ui.helper.index() - (ui.helper.index() % 3)) / 3;
        var placeholderIndex = ui.helper.index() % 3;
        var noMargin = resetGroup * 3 + 4;

        if (placeholderIndex === 0 || placeholderIndex == 1) {
            $(".ui-sortable-placeholder").css('margin-right', '40px')
        }
        if (placeholderIndex == 2) {
            $(".ui-sortable-placeholder").css('margin-right', '0px');
        }

        $("#sample-list .sample:nth-child(3n+" + noMargin + ")").css("margin-right", "0px");

    },
```

Then on change, the position of the placeholder jumps to the new element you're hovering on so we need to reset the margins again..

```
'change': function(event, ui) {

    $("#sample-list .sample:nth-child(n)").css("margin-right", "40px");

    $(ui.helper[0].parentElement).children().not(".ui-sortable-helper").each(function(index) {
        if (index % 3 == 2) {
            $(this).css("margin-right", "0px");
        }
    });

},
```

Finally, once the sort is finished (you let go of the mouse and drop the element in place), you need to run another reset of the margins..

```
'stop': function(event, ui) {

    $("#sample-list > div:nth-child(n)").css("margin-right", "40px");
    $("#sample-list > div:nth-child(3n+3)").css("margin-right", "0px");

},
```

This all worked for me but I'm sure there must be better options for doing this.

Question 2:
Right now i'm using a solution from here to stop the initial jump: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11874958/3656694

But on initial load, the element still jumps out of view. I have to let it go and grab it again to be able to move and actually see where I'm moving it to.

I have a mimicked set up over here. I hope this helps others as it took me a while to get together!
https://jsfiddle.net/restlessweb/wh4w2jaf/

**Edit:**
For question 2 I actually ended up going with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24122186/3656694 - where you set the sortable list to `overflow: auto` - for this to work though I had to have a newer version of jQuery than the one I was running. I was on 1.11 but updated to 2.2.0 and everything started working better.

I've updated the fiddle to reflect the above.